# Add jsp directive from server side

Tags: java, jdom

i wanna do something like

```
Document dom = new Document();
Element ele = new Element("jsp:include");
dom.setRootElement(ele);
```

but its throwing error i am using jdom for getting dom(`org.jdom.Document`, `org.jdom.Element`)

whats wrong in doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("jsp", "http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page");
    Element element = new Element("include", ns);
    Document dom = new Document(element);
```